# Does there exist a prime number decomposition for ordinal numbers?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, ordinals

As is well known, each natural number (except $0$) can be written uniquely as product of finitely many prime numbers (with $1$ being the empty product). My question is: Does some analogue theorem also hold for ordinal numbers?

Comment: Well, $\omega = 2 \times \omega$, so.... Also, unique prime factorization is up to order, and it's unclear what this means for ordinal multiplication, which is noncommutative.

Comment: Good point. But what if we add the condition that the numbers must be multiplied in decreasing order? For natural numbers, this would not make a difference, and for infinite numbers, I believe it should resolve this specific problem. Or alternatively one could use the natural (Hessenberg) product.

Comment: Well, $(\omega + 1) \times \omega = (\omega + 2) \times \omega$, so...

Comment: Oh, right. So even with the ordering requirement, for the normal ordinal product, it cannot work. However, what about the natural (Hessenberg) product?

Comment: This is a very interesting question!  I believe the question you are asking is whether or not the ordinals form a UFD using natural sum and product.  The ordinals below $\omega^\omega$ endowed with natural sum and product are isomorphic to polynomials with natural number coefficients, so they form a UFD.  I believe this remains true for higher ordinals, but I don't have a proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theorem 3 of Shinpei Oka's *On Telgárski's formula* (online [summary](http://www.kurims.kyoto-u.ac.jp/~kyodo/kokyuroku/contents/pdf/1634-13.pdf)) offers an affirmative answer.

Comment: Sierpinski's book **Cardinal and Ordinal Numbers** is pretty much the bible for this kind of stuff. I don't have my copy with me where I'm at right now to give any suggestions based on it, but since no one else has yet mentioned Sierpinski's book, I thought I'd mention it in case the OP doesn't know about it.